# Fetching data from table, RewardsPoint Extension: Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to fetch data using this query:[Written in the observer file of RewardPonts extension].

```
public function salesOrderInvoiceSaveAfter($observer)
{


$id=$observer['invoice']->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
  echo $id;
  $custom=$observer['invoice']->getOrder()->getCustomerId();
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  $table = $resource->getTableName('marketplace/saleslist');
  $result = $readConnection->fetchCol('SELECT mageproownerid FROM '.$table.'WHERE magerealorderid='.$id.
  'AND magebuyerid='.$custom);
      var_dump($result);
  $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
  foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $name = $item->getName();
     $type = $item->getSku();
     $id = $item->getProductId();
     $qty = $item->getQty();
     $price = $item->getPrice();
     echo $name.",".$type.",".$id.",".$qty.",".$price; 
  }
```

But its not returning any result. Can we use direct sql query inside the extension, if yes then what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You need to debug your code.

```
$query = 'SELECT mageproownerid FROM '.$table.' WHERE
                               magerealorderid='.$id. ' AND magebuyerid='.$custom;
var_dump($query);  
$result = $readConnection->fetchCol($query);
var_dump($result);
```

First check query print output of query then also check in database if it is working then there will be no problem.

I think that you need to put space between **' and where** & **' and AND** in your query.

Comment: Yes you were right the problem was the space between "where" & "and".